# How to read JSON array in Laravel 5.3

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5

I need to get latitude and longitude from this array:

```
AddressCollection {#237 ▼
-addresses: array:1 [▼
0 => Address {#232 ▼
  -coordinates: Coordinates {#233 ▼
    -latitude: 55.923431
    -longitude: 23.3490609
  }
  -bounds: Bounds {#234 ▶}
  -streetNumber: "18"
  -streetName: "Vilniaus gatvė"
  -subLocality: null
  -locality: "Šiauliai"
  -postalCode: "76258"
  -adminLevels: AdminLevelCollection {#235 ▶}
  -country: Country {#236 ▶}
  -timezone: null
}
]
}
```

Code in my controller:

```
 $posts = Post::latest()->get();  
     Mapper::location('Lietuva')->map(['zoom' => 7, 'scrollWheelZoom'=>false, 'marker'=>false]); //A map is displayed in the index page
    foreach($posts as $post){

        $city = $post->city;
        $address = $post->address;

        $mark = app('geocoder')->geocode($city . $address)->get();

        dd($mark);
        //
        //THIS IS WHERE I NEED THOSE COODINATES
        //
        //For example $lat = $mark->coordinates.......

        //Mapper::marker($lat, $long); Make a marker for every address in the DB
    }
 return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
```

Not sure if this will generate markers for my map, but i still have no idea how to get specific information from JSON array. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Per the docs you should be able to do `$marker->first()->getCoordinates()`?

Comment: @jfadich It worked, how should i now access latitude and longitude? I have this now: Coordinates {#233 ▼
  -latitude: 55.923431
  -longitude: 23.3490609
}

Comment: Did you try anything before asking? Again per the Docs it's just `$marker->first()->getCoordinates()->getLatitude()` or `$marker->first()->getCoordinates()->getLongitude()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first address from the collection you do:

```
$address = $marker->first();
```

To get the coordinates you can call `getCoordinates()` on the address.

```
$coordinates = $address->getCoordinates();
```

Once you have the coordinates you just need to call the `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` methods to get the latitude and longitude respectively.

```
$longitude = $coordinates->getLongitude();
$latitude  = $coordinates->getLatitude();
```